# Can i replace 1n4148 with 1n4007 in this circuit (pic Programmer)

Tags: pic, diodes, pic16f

I want to conceive a pic programmer i found this circuit but  i didn't find 1n4148 can i remplace it with 1n4001/1n4007 in  this circuit It affects the pic or dysfunction of the system in speed ou current  [image: pic Programmer]

Comment: Ya a 1n4001 will be fine.

Comment: 1n4148 is a small-signal diode, the 1n400x are rectifier diodes that can handle power but might be slower or have higher forward voltage. 1N4148s are dirt cheap and readily available. If you can source the zeners then you can source the 48s or something similar.

Comment: But please go ahead and try it will probably work.

Comment: wondering what the little circuit top right is supposed to do...

Comment: The diodes can only protect as fast as they can respond.  Fortunately the PIC already has small Schottky diodes on those pins for a certain amount of  uJ protection from ESD.  This has a higher forward voltage. So a Schottky diode is preferred.

Comment: @Trevor - that's probably for providing a higher-than-5V Vpp programming supply to the PIC.

Comment: @brhans, yes that's what I figured too... still looks strange though.

Comment: @Trevor - it seems that the RS232 TX line is being used in an imaginative way to both power the circuit and also provide Vpp when necessary. Note that Pin-5 on the DB-9 is connected to the circuit's +5V net, while that is actually GND on the serial port ...

Comment: @brhans, lol sneaky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 4007 here. Orr a shottky diode, or a small signal BJT. Pretty much anything works here, other than high power rectifiers